# How to check if files are uploaded PHP

Tags: php

I need to check if files are uploaded in PHP and after checking redirect user on other page. Problem is that when I redirect user not all files are uploaded, so I need to check them and then redirect user. Here is my code:

```
                if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){

                    if($file_error === 0) {
                        if($file_size <= 2097152) {
                            $last_id = $connect->insert_id;
                            $file_name_new = uniqid('',true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                            $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;

                            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
                                $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
                                header("Location: ../naxva.php?operation=success");
                                exit();
                                
                            } else {
                                $failed[$position] = "[$file_name] failed to upload";
                            }

                        } else {
                            $failed[$position] = "[$file_name] is too large.";
                        }

                    } else {
                        $failed[$position] = "[$file_name] errored with code {$file_error}.";
                    }

                } else {
                    header("Location: ../naxva.php?operation=cudifile");
                }
```

Comment: Are you saying that `move_uploaded_file()` returned without an error, but the file wasn't actually moved?

Comment: What's the point of assigning to `$uploaded[$position]` immediately before `exit()`? The variable will be lost.

Comment: Yes, when I deleted header and exit functions, all files were uploaded

Comment: Is this part of a loop? You're exiting the script after moving the first file, so the loop stops and the rest of the files are not moved.

Comment: Do you understand what `exit()` does?

Comment: I am learning this stuff right now and I followed the tutorial, So I didn't understand why he did this so this is why asked here

Comment: This code is only appropriate for uploading one file, not multiple files.

Comment: So I got it right now, I need to move exit() and header out of the loop?

Comment: That's correct. At the end of the loop, check whether `$failed` is empty. If it is, you can redirect and exit. If not, you should report the errors.

Comment: Okay thank you very much